# Auto trigged BackColor of checkedlistBox items

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, backcolor

Heyy C# newbie here .. I have 2 checkListBox with 3 elements. When I click on any element of either, I want the other's element in the same index to change its backcolor. Is there a defined function to do this? If there is how and in which private void I will use it ?? Thanks from advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4run.png)...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Not an option for CheckedListBox.  Get ahead with ListView, View = List, CheckBoxes = True.  ListViewItem.BackColor to change the color of an item.